# Ansible - How to access debug output from register?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

****Hello.
Please help me with below.
I want to access '3.21.228.186' of
"public_ip": "3.21.228.186".
What should be debug-var variable ?
##########Full output:**

```
How can I solve this ?

> ok: [localhost] => {
> 
>     "start_AWS": {
> 
>         "changed": true,
> 
>         "failed": false,
> 
>         "instance_ids": [
> 
>             "i-12233ef3073q3622sad7baweq3445af406526"
> 
>         ],
> 
>         "instances": [
> 
>             {
> 
>                 "ami_launch_index": "0",
> 
>                 "architecture": "x86_64",
> 
>                 "block_device_mapping": {
> 
>                     "/dev/sda1": {
> 
>                         "delete_on_termination": true,
> 
>                         "status": "attached",
> 
>                         "volume_id": "vol-043ce7d3375a194d7"
> 
>                     }
> 
>                 },
> 
>                 "dns_name": "ec2-3-21-228-186.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
> 
>                 "ebs_optimized": false,
> 
>                 "groups": {
> 
>                     "sg-0d1460e84b87c3945": "launch-wizard-1"
> 
>                 },
> 
>                 "hypervisor": "xen",
> 
>                 "id": "i-0safdfsdf736gfd22sdfsdfsd7baaf406526",
> 
>                 "image_id": "ami-0a91cd140a1fc148a",
> 
>                 "instance_type": "t2.micro",
> 
>                 "kernel": null,
> 
>                 "key_name": "hem",
> 
>                 "launch_time": "2021-01-21T03:50:01.000Z",
> 
>                 "placement": "us-east-2b",
> 
>                 "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-24-208.us-east-2.compute.internal",
> 
>                 "private_ip": "172.31.24.208",
> 
>                 "public_dns_name": "ec2-3-21-228-186.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
> 
>                 "public_ip": "3.21.228.186",
> 
>                 "ramdisk": null,
> 
>                 "region": "us-east-2",
> 
>                 "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1",
> 
>                 "root_device_type": "ebs",
> 
>                 "state": "running",
> 
>                 "state_code": 16,
> 
>                 "tags": {
> 
>                     "Name": "ubuntu"
> 
>                 },
> 
>                 "tenancy": "default",
> 
>                 "virtualization_type": "hvm"
> 
>             }
> 
>         ],
> 
>         "tagged_instances": []
> 
>     }
> 
> }
```

---

> How can I solve this ? Thanks in advance

---

## Please help.

I am trying to take this output and give it as input to another task

Thanks,
Srivi

Please ignore below
Dummy details for error “It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instances` is a list, you can create a loop to print each `public_ip` as below:

```yaml
- name: Print public ip
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
  with_items: "{{ your_register_var.instances }}"
```

or if you know you'll have just one instance try as below

```yaml
- name: Print public ip
  debug:
    msg: "{{ your_register_var.instances[0].public_ip }}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I see TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "start_AWS.instances[0].public_ip": "3.138.141.178"
}